# Hibernation does not work in 11.04, used to work in 10.10, but suspend/resume works fine on a Dell Inspiron N5010

Tags: 11.04, dell, hibernate, inspiron

I upgraded to 11.04 on the day for its release and I am unable to
 hibernate my laptop, When I click on Hibernate, the screen just goes blank and cursor starts blinking in the top left corner and nothing happens. . It used to work fine till 10.10.
 Suspend/Resume works fine though.
 I am using 11.04 64bit on Dell Inspiron N5010 it have ATI graphics
 card and I am using propriety drivers for it installed via jockey.
 Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it doesn't work".  What happens when you try?

Comment: When I click on Hibernate, the screen just goes blank and cursor starts blinking in the top left corner and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have solved this problem. The solution is to use tuxonice patched kernel. Its very simple, just follow these steps.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tuxonice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tuxonice-userui linux-generic-tuxonice linux-headers-generic-tuxonice
```

Restart your system. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a better method documented to enable hibernation. If this doesn't work, probably you don't have enough space in your swap drive to hibernate.

[How do I hibernate my computer?](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html)